# ajax post appends data to url

Tags: javascript, ajax

I searched for this problem but the answers I found haven't worked for me.  Here is my js script.

```
$("#edit-btn").click(function() {
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: $(this).data("url"),
    data: { "UserID" : $(this).data("id") },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus);
    }
})
```

})

When this code is executed, I get "The requested URL /user_update.php4 was not found on this server." in my browser.  "user_update.php" is the value of $(this).data("url") and "4" is the value of $(this).data("id").

Any help most welcome.

Comment: Well looks like your server does not have a file named: user_update.php4, you are probably needing to send the request like: user_update.php/4 or user_update.php?id=4, depending on your server route config

Comment: @DZDomi - it's a POST request ... jquery.ajax does not append random numbers to the URL

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks i know that, but in this post he says user_update.php4 is not found, maybe its a type dont know

Comment: question also "states" that `"user_update.php" is the value of $(this).data("url")` not `"user_update.php4"`

Comment: @Pete, your code works fine for me (Firefox 50.1.0, JQuery 2.1.2, bare-bones Node Express server).  It generates a POST request for the URL with no trailing garbage, and it passes the UserID in the request body, as intended.  Is it possible your server is a broken development server that is mis-parsing the POST request from the browser?  If your browser has a development console with a network panel, can you verify which URL the browser is posting to?   Maybe a self-contained HTML example, including jQuery from a CDN would help debug the issue.

Comment: Check the Network tab of the web console to see what URL you're sending to. Maybe the problem is a rewrite rule on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input.  This morning, the same code is working.  My computer has been closed down and started up again since I posted the question so maybe there was an issue that was fixed that way or maybe javascript caching (I changed the script several times).  In any case, all is working OK now.
Pete